# CSS Transitions lag

Tags: css, html, mobile, lag

This HTML5/CSS theme works perfectly from desktop and also in mobile version always from desktop browser, but there is a lag during transitions on mobile browser (tested with chrome and firefox).

Someone can help me to improve the CSS ? I've tested many solutions, like enabling hardware acceleration with transform css propriety, but nothing seem to working.

This is the theme: https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Comment: Just see the css from source: https://html5up.net/uploads/demos/dimension/assets/css/main.css

Comment: @walter4991, it's important to include some source code in your question, otherwise it becomes useless to anyone searching in future if that link stops working.

Comment: I agree with @Beejamin. Also, the problem may not be your CSS code and we can't help you if you don't include all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Without digging too deeply into it, the lag when clicking the menu items is caused by transitioning the `blur` filter on that big background image. It's just an inherently expensive operation, and it's combined with transitioning the `scale` transform as well.

There are some tricks in this area, such as switching in a low-res, up-scaled image for the blur, but they are really hacks - the short answer is, if you need smooth transition performance, don't animate filter on complex elements, and definitely don't animate combined filters and other operations at the same time.

As a quick fix, find the `body.is-article-visible #bg:after` section in the stylesheet, and remove the transform: scale(); lines so that the background is only blurring, not blurring and scaling:

```
body.is-article-visible #bg:after {
    -moz-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    -ms-filter: blur(0.2rem);
    filter: blur(0.2rem);
}
```

That makes a big difference to performance on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for the info, anyway i've removed all the scale transitions, and the lag decreased but not totally disappeared